# Ansible: How to check files is changed in shell command?

Tags: ansible

I have file, generated by shell command

```
- stat: path=/etc/swift/account.ring.gz get_md5=yes
  register: account_builder_stat

- name: write account.ring.gz file
  shell: swift-ring-builder account.builder write_ring <--- rewrite account.ring.gz
    chdir=/etc/swift
  changed_when: ??? account_builder_stat.changed ??? <-- no give desired effect
```

How can I check that the file has been changed?

Comment: ?? do you have the old md5 in some variable? can you post the task that changes the file too?

Comment: @thekashyap variable account_builder_stat contain old md5. File change with shell command the above code

Answer (score 11, accepted):

```
- stat: path=/etc/swift/account.ring.gz get_md5=yes
  register: before

- name: write account.ring.gz file
  shell: swift-ring-builder account.builder write_ring # update account.ring.gz
    chdir=/etc/swift
  changed_when: False # without this, as long as swift-ring-builder exits with
                      # return code 0 this task would always be reported as changed

- stat: path=/etc/swift/account.ring.gz get_md5=yes
  register: after

- debug: msg='report this task as "changed" if file changed'
  changed_when: "'{{before.stat.md5}}' != '{{after.stat.md5}}'"

- debug: msg='execute this task if file changed'
  when: "'{{before.stat.md5}}' != '{{after.stat.md5}}'"
```

If what you really want is to report the task 'write account.ring.gz file' as changed or not changed based on outcome of `swift-ring-builder` then you have to run a mini shell script. Something like this (not tested):

```
- name: write account.ring.gz file
  shell: bfr=`md5sum account.ring.gz`; swift-ring-builder account.builder write_ring; aftr=`md5sum account.ring.gz`; test $bfr -eq $aftr
    chdir=/etc/swift
```

or if I remember the md5sum options correctly:

```
- name: write account.ring.gz file
  shell: echo `md5sum account.ring.gz` account.ring.gz > /tmp/ff; swift-ring-builder account.builder write_ring; md5sum -c /tmp/ff
    chdir=/etc/swift
```

Answer (score -1):

Following @Kashyap's answer you can also do a diff between the two files but if the two files differ, diff will result in error and it will stop your playbook's run.

Comment: You can also set `ignore_errors`  to `yes` if you want to avoid stopping the playbook's run, but if the diff is a show stopper, then stopping is a good idea.

Comment: `falied_when: thisTask.rc not in [0, 1]` is an alternative to `ignore_errors: yes` (do `register: thisTask` on the task) see https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_error_handling.html#defining-failure

Comment: In case you want to get diff output the ansible way, see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43096404/ansible-use-of-diff-command-using-ansible/48769623#comment113761636_48769623